# .htaccess to show a page from the main site on another domain

Tags: htaccess, redirects, dns, url-rewriting

I have 2 x domain names

- `https://www.example.com` - This is my main site.
- `http://www.example-liverpool.com`

This is my Liverpool sub website `example.com/liverpool` I've presently got URL forwarding from `www.example-liverpool.com` to the above URL, but as it was in a frame, the responsive nature of the sub site is crap! I've now switched off the forwarding stealth (frame) and waiting for it to replicate.

Now for my question. Is there a way of using the `.htaccess` file so that when I open `example-liverpool.com` to open the `/liverpool` page that it can display the `example-liverpool.com` URL and not the `example.com` one?

This is not a spoofing question, reason I want to do this is that the main website is a national organisation that are finding it difficult to get funding for. Having created a sub domain `/liverpool` means I can apply for local funding.  Having the local domain name being displayed shows that we are local.  Is what I'm asking possible?

Both domains are the same organisation.

Comment: You have both `https` and `http` - is that a typo or intentional? Where does `example-liverpool.com` (your second domain) currently point to? What kind of hosting do you have? What hosting _control panel_? Presumably you also require `example-liverpool.com/<whatever>` to return `example.com/liverpool/<whatever>`? Or is simply that one page `/liverpool` that you are returning?